# Github Actions Conditional Trigger

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I need help figuring something, I am trying to trigger 2 different workflows based on 2 different release tags. I want prod-* to trigger the production workflow and dev-* for the development workflow.

The problem is both tags trigger both workflows and I have no idea how to fix this

[image]

(I've canceled both actions but they triggered as you can see)
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **`tags`** element is not valid for `release` events. In consequence, the workflow is triggered for every `release` event of type *published* no matter the tag. There is no direct filter for tags with the [`release`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onevent_nametypes) event as there is for [`push`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags) and [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags) events.

So you can leverage the `if` conditional on jobs in combination with the `github.ref` in the context which contains the *tag of the release*.

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  deploy-dev:
    name: Deploy to development
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/dev-')
    steps:
      # [...]

  deploy-prod:
    name: Deploy to production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/prod-')
    steps:
      # [...]
```

Comment: We both did the same thing in different ways. However your solution looks easier (without using `outputs`) for being less verbose. Great answer 

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thank you. Yes, the idea is basically the same and it is always great to see how things can be solved in different ways.

Answer (score 4):

The `published` trigger is used in both cases here (independently of the tag), because your workflow will start for published `OR` tags (with the informed pattern) events.

To perform an operation only for a specific tag, you would have to extract the tag version from the `$GITHUB_REF` (env-var), for example using a step as below with an output in a first job:

```
- name: Get the version 
  id: get_tag_version 
  run: echo ::set-output name=version::${GITHUB_REF/refs\/tags\//}
```

And then use an `if condition` on 2 others jobs to check if the tag version *contains* `prod-` or `dev-` (needing the first job) to perform the operation you want for each scenario.

Here is an complete example of what could be used:

```
name: Example

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      tag_version: ${{ steps.get_tag_version.outputs.version }}
    steps:
     - name: Get the version 
       id: get_tag_version 
       run: echo ::set-output name=version::${GITHUB_REF/refs\/tags\//}

   job2: # will be executed on for dev- tag
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job1]
    if: contains( needs.job1.outputs.tag_version , 'dev-')
    steps:
     [...]

   job3: # will be executed on for prod- tag
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job1]
    if: contains( needs.job1.outputs.tag_version , 'prod-')
    steps:
     [...]
```

I coded a workflow to test the implementation above and it worked as expected creating a `prod-2` release tag:

- [workflow file implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester8.yml)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1078607718)

[image: Example]

*EDIT: Note that you could also use a `startWith` instead of a `contains` function for the if expression.*